# Help Me Understand This Comment Re Page Lifecycle

Tags: c#, asp.net

I encountered this comment recently:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) {
// doing this at PreRender so we don't have to worry about when/if 
// we should bind based on if it's a postback or callback and what not.
OrderList.DataSource = OrderItems;
OrderList.DataBind(); }
```

I was under the impression that PreRender fired every time Load fires, as part of normal page lifecycle, so what's the advantage of doing databinding here?

Answer (score 1):

if you use PreRender, you can manage any control at this point, just before page goes for display.  PreRender occurs in the very end, after all events have occured

---

This article explains all from start to finish, in

[**Control Execution Life Cycle**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719775(VS.71).aspx)

hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I know. But isn't this code effectively the same as setting the datasourceID on page load and not doing anything on PreRender? I don't understand his comment about binding "based on if it's a postback or callback and what not."

Comment: one guess is, OrderList.DataSource id is not dependant over PostBack etc. For that reason, one considered to put that piece of code here

Answer (score 0):

I see no advantage of doing that in response to that event.  As far as the specific PostBack comment, he's referring to code like this:

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: Lots of code in Page_Load is dependent on whether or not the processing is being done as a result of a postback, and there are some things in that code that must be decided *before* the binding is made. The commenter therefore believes that maintenance will be easier if the .databind() call is made in some later part of the lifecycle, which makes more clear the fact that the binding is independent of the codepaths in Page_Load.